# How to show that $\displaystyle{\cot z-\frac{1}{z}}$ is bounded on the given circle

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

$$f(z)=\cot z - \frac{1}{z}=\frac{z \cos z - \sin z}{z ~ \sin z}$$
having poles at $z=n \pi$ with residue $1$ at each pole. Also $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0.$ All these are asked to calculate and I've done that. If $C_N$ is the circle enclosing all the poles having the center at the origin and radius $R_N,$ how can I show that $f$ is bounded on $C_N$ for a suitable $R_N$ ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: [image]Note that

Comment: Because $f$ is continuous on a compact set?

Comment: @JackyChong That's what I thought at the beginning since there were no poles on the boundary. Is there a way to select an appropriate $R_N ?$

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. What is the significance of $N$? Would choosing $R_N=0.01$ be a satisfactory answer?

Comment: @Lubin 'N' is sufficiently large number, as we choose in $\epsilon-N$ arguments.

Comment: Then what is the dependence of $R_N$ on $N$?

Comment: All I have is that it should be "large" enough to enclose all the poles. This is a method of proving Mittag-Leffler's theorem. Eventually the idea is to let $N$ and simltaneously $R_N \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: There are infinitely many poles; one at $k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. No circle can contain them all.

Comment: Apologies for not being precise. I've edited the question by adding the precise statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $R_N = (\pi/2)(2N + 1)$ so that $C_N$ does not intersect the poles. We have
$$\vert f(z) \vert \leq \vert \cot z \vert + \vert 1/z \vert.$$
The $1/z$ part can be made arbitrarily small by choosing a sufficiently large $R_N$. You can show $\vert cot z \vert \leq \vert \coth y \vert$, where $y = \textrm{Im}(z)$. Now if $\vert y \vert > \vert y' \vert$ then $\vert \coth y \vert < \vert \coth y' \vert$, so we can bound $\cot z$ on the parts of $C_N$ where $\textrm{Im}(z) \geq y$ for some chosen $y > 0$. The problem is that $\vert \coth y \vert$ approaches $\infty$ as $y \to 0$. However, this is easy to circumvent because $\cot z$ is periodic. Simply choose a closed square centered at $\pi/2$ which avoids the poles $0$ and $\pi$, then take the max of $\vert \cot z \vert$ on this square. By periodicity, this bound will work near the real points of $C_N$ for any $N \geq 0$.

Comment: @ Ethan Alwaise thank you.